# Python modulo diff ans?

Tags: python, double, modulo

while solving mathematical problem i get this problem . same type of operation geeting diff ans
mod=1e9+21

```
  mod=1000000000+21
  for i in range(20,21):
  f3=pow(math.sqrt(7),i+2)*math.cos(i*math.atan(math.sqrt(3)/2))  #combine

  x1=pow(math.sqrt(7),i+2)%mod #diff
  x2=math.cos(i*math.atan(math.sqrt(3)/2))%mod

  print((x1*x2)%mod)
  print(f3%mod)
```

```
output

866216427.0

729324812.000003
```

i try to compute combine modulo then i get 866216427.0 as an output .then i try individual now i get diff ans than first one .

How i resolve this error as i know f3 ans is correct

```
F1=f1*f2*f3
print(F1%mod)

or you do either in this format
 F1=(((f1%mod)*(f2%mod))%mod*(f3%mod))%mod
 you get same ans as per modulo property . 

i am using same propery then why i am geeting diff ans
```

Answer (score 2):

You're applying identities that are valid for integers in a context (floats) where they aren't.

Make it very simple:  4 is congruent to 8 modulo 4 (both are congruent to 0), but it's *not* the case that 4 * (1/4) = 1 is congruent to 8 * (1/4) = 2 modulo 4.  You can multiply both sides by an integer and maintain the congruence, but not necessarily so if you multiply by a non-integral real.

Same basic problem in your code, but here illustrated with numbers you can work out in your head:

```py
>>> a = 1000.0
>>> b = 0.5
>>> c = a
>>> ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c
0.0
>>> (a * b) % c
500.0
```

Note that the expressions do give the same values if `a`, `b`, and `c` are all integers - but `b = 0.5` breaks it.

Which is "right"? There is no answer to that: they're different expressions that compute different results.

### A bit of insight

When working modulo `c`, we're working with values that are an integer multiple of `c` removed from the infinitely precisely values. So, e.g., mathematically,

```
a % c = a - n1 * c
and
b % c = b - n2 * c
```

for some integers `n1` and `n2`.  If we add those,

```
a % c + b % c = a + b - (n1 + n2) * c
```

so the result is still an integer multiple (`n1 + n2`) of `c` removed from the infinitely precise result (`a + b`).

But if we multiply them,

```
(a % c) * (b % c) =
(a - n1 * c) * (b - n2 * c) =
a*b + (n1 * n2 * c - n1 * b - n2 * a) * c
```

That's an integer multiple of `c` removed from the infinitely precise result (`a*b`) if and only if `n1 * n2 * c - n1 * b - n2 * a` is an integer.  Which it must be if `a`, `b`, and `c` are all integers, but it depends on the precise values if they're not. And that's why the identities you're relying on always work for integers but may not for non-integers.